# Imperfect Subjunctive for Politeness

Tags: subjuntivo

I saw something very bizarre in one of my Spanish-English grammar books. They recommended the use of the imperfect subjunctive in independent clauses for politeness.[image]

I have asked as many native speakers as I can, across Spain, the US, and Latin America, and no one has yet to tell me that they've heard this or that it even sounds correct. I myself cannot find references online that back this grammar book up.

Are there any grammarians here who can verify the existence of this form of polite requests?

Comment: Except for the first sentence, I have been speaking, reading and writing in Spanish all my life and this is the first time I read this. Surely it is not common and I assure you that nobody uses it that way.

Comment: I imagine there are situations where I could say something like that, but I wouldn't do it out of politeness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of the imperfect subjunctive (*cantara*) instead of the conditional (*cantaría*) is documented in Sections [24.2m to 24.2o](https://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SeUXxloRgNQzxqlO) of the *Nueva gramática de la lengua española* (NGLE).

The summary is that it was common in classical Spanish to use *cantara* in sentences which today would require *cantaría*. This usage is much less common today, but still persists in some cases, such as in popular/rural language in Venezuela, Honduras, Cuba, Puerto Rico and Costa Rica.

An exception are the modal verbs *poder*, *deber* and *querer*, where the alternative use of the imperfect of subjunctive and the conditional is still common today:

- No trabajas tanto como (debieras/deberías).
- (Podría/pudiera) ser que ganara el campeonato.
- (Quisiera/querría) ser un pez.

Generally, NGLE and other sources (e.g. [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/subjuntivo-en-condicionales-569/)) consider it uncommon but not incorrect to use the imperfect of subjunctive instead of the conditional with these verbs or with any other verb in the *then* part of a conditional sentence.

However, **none of the sources mention that this usage is a form of politeness**.

Comment: I agree. Actually, "quisiera" (which I use) is as polite as "querría", but this is due to the use of the verb "querer" in a tentative way, instead of the rather blunt "quiero".

Answer (score 1):

Por más que lo intento, no logro explicarme cómo se puede editar y publicar un libro con ejemplos como los que tú mismo transcribes.

Por cierto, estos ejemplos se podrían traducir de otra forma, que un hablante de español (nativo) vería con mucha menos extrañeza:

- *Me gustaría hacerlo.*
- *¿Podrías pasarme la sal?*
- *Deberían comprarlos.*

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de frases hay que circunscribirlas a contextos amplios donde se recogen y exponen distintas variaciones de comunidades hispanoparlantes y que forman parte del aprendizaje y enseñanza del idioma español, pues a pesar de su uso restringido y características poco frecuentes para la mayoría, incluso para sectores amplios de población nativa, no por ello carecen de validez.

El Instituto Cervantes, recoge varios "Corpus" (*textos en formato electrónico que han sido reunidos en una aplicación informática*),  más o menos amplios que pretenden facilitar el estudio de la lengua, estos, reúnen distintas variedades lingüísticas y sirven para extraer textos que no solo sirven para el aprendizaje, sino también para la enseñanza y la investigación entre los gramáticos.

A su vez, de los muchos tipos y subtipos de corpus existentes, se encuentra el llamado "Corpus de aprendices de español", (CAES), un conjunto de textos escritos por estudiantes de español con distinto grado en el dominio del idioma.

A veces, el uso del español se convierte en parte de la gramática avanzada del mismo español, ya que los datos que se recogen proceden del corpus de español-L1 y L2 y de ahí la dificultad aparente de ciertas variaciones lingüísticas que no son explicadas apropiadamente, pues no describen las características léxico-gramaticales de la investigación lingüística que desarrollan.

Con frecuencia se utilizan libros de texto para la enseñanza del español con el fin de que los estudiantes puedan buscar dentro de los distintos "corpus", y así llegar a conclusiones sobre como "otros aprendices" utilizan ciertos elementos léxico-gramaticales que tienen en cuenta diferentes variaciones de distintas zonas hispanoparlantes.

Hay que tener en cuenta que la forma del "voseo" en el español americano, lleva consigo una alteración de la entonación y una formulación distinta del propio verbo (voseo verbal).

De esta manera en casos como los que aparecen expuestos más arriba, por ejemplo, "**¿Pudieras pasarme la sal?**", decir que existen comunidades lingüísticas de hispanoparlantes, preferentemente dentro de esas "zonas voseantes", en las que la utilización del "modo imperativo" tiene un efecto práctico distinto al empleado por el resto de hispanohablantes, y así el peso del mandato que normalmente utiliza la persona para dar órdenes, consejos o solicitar peticiones de forma directa, es atenuado por las "**reglas de cortesía**" que toleran o admiten el uso del subjuntivo o del condicional.

De esta manera, en lugar de decir "¡Pásame la sal!", la inevitable "cortesía" hacia la otra persona, (el otro comensal), orienta hacia la utilización de un pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo, "pudieras",  "¿Pudieras pasarme la sal?" o un condicional simple, "podrías", "¿Podrías pasarme la sal?".

---

Notas;

- Corpus de aprendices de español (CAES)

https://www.cervantes.es/lengua_y_ensenanza/tecnologia_espanol/caes.htm

- Los corpus textuales del español

[https://gramatica.usc.es/~grojo/Publicaciones/corpus_textuales_espanol_borrador_final.pdf](https://gramatica.usc.es/%7Egrojo/Publicaciones/corpus_textuales_espanol_borrador_final.pdf)

- El léxico-gramática del español. Una aproximación mediante la lingüística de corpus. (Routledge Introductions to Spanish Language and Linguistics). PorAlan V Brown,Yanira B Paz,Conde Kjar Brown. Edición en Inglés

*Este libro brinda al estudiante un enfoque auténtico y contextualizado del uso del español, basándose en datos provenientes de corpus de español-L1 y L2 junto a la investigación lingüística a fin de describir las características léxico-gramaticales fundamentales de la lengua y su variación*.

https://www.amazon.es/l%C3%A9xico-gram%C3%A1tica-del-espa%C3%B1ol-aproximaci%C3%B3n-ling%C3%BC%C3%ADstica/dp/0367133539

- La estilística del verbo. Valores semánticos y estilísticos de la formas verbales

http://www.materialesdelengua.org/LENGUA/morfologia/verbo/estilistica.htm

---